# Select2 default value by id

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown, and I have the **id** of the option.

How do I set it to the specific **id** when loading the page?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#region-select").select2().select2('id', '2');

  });
</script>
```

Is not doing anything.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#select").select2("val", 2); ` ??

Answer (score 2):

Please use `val` instead of `id`.

This should work :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#region-select").select2().select2('val', '2');

});
```

Comment: Its not changing it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and write what is their in your options?

Comment: If your select has options like `<option value="game2">Game 2</option>` present in the dropdown... so, maybe in your case it should be `select2('val', 'game2')` instead.